# Alternatives of session variables?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a web app for a business which includes several departments. I am using PHP and MySql to do this, in my database i am storing the privileges as ENUM with options N (No access), R (Read Only) and RW (Read and Write).

Once a user logs in, a php script finds the appropriate privileges and stores those in a session. For example: if a user has RW for Production, then there is a session variable `$_SESSION['production'] = RW`. Now whenever i need to see if a user is allowed to edit production then i check with the session variable and take appropriate actions.

I have 20 such categories of privileges. This certainly isn't the way store something like this. This will simply increase the load time and hog plenty of memory. Are there any alternatives to store the `user rights`?

Note: The 20 category list is expected to grow.

Comment: I think session is for this kind of stuff. Storing in database would use more resources. And storing in cookie is a no here.

I would. Make groups. Like group 1 has full-privileges, group 2 has less, group 4 has none. Something like that. Sorry if I am not clear.

Comment: Well i already have groups like if there is a category of Production, now that has sub-gourps like production_orders etc, thats is what i am storing in sessions. However it just seems not a very efficient way. Hope this made it clear, let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I typically use

```
$_SESSION['privileges']=array(
  'someprivilege' => 'r',
  'someotherprivilege' => 'rw'
)
```

to keep the memory requirements in context: 100 privileges, the name consisting of 20 chars, the value of 5 chars, will add up to less than a page (4k). The load time issue is heavily mitgated by PHP using a very efficient bnary serializer on session files.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you store access rights in database and check them when you need by user id?
You'll need to store only user id in $_SESSION.
This simplifies the whole application.

If you store access rights in session, you need to be always sure they they are always up to date at any single point of time. For example if admin wants to change user access rights, they need to have additional ability to log user out. OR for example you need to update your $_SESSION everytime user tries to access the page, which is overhead and anyway requires checking database every time.

Comment: I was doing that initially, but i was told by my supervisor (database professor) that it isn't a good idea to actually run that query for every page. He asked me to store them locally and then access them, as it increases the speed of the of loading the page.

Comment: you could use cache to avoid running query every time. You will be able to flush the cache when need to change access rights. And you will not need to ask user to log in/out

Comment: This is a good idea, but being a business application, cache would raise security issues later.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an identity class that encapsulate all your users informations (id, privileges and have in it getters for those properties) and have it instanciated once the user is logged in by getting privileges from DB by using user's id.

then each time you need to find his rights just call getRights(); from your identity class.

Answer (score 0):

You should only pick the permissions when they apply. This will keep your load limited to what is needed.

Alternatively you could store the permissions per user in a serialized form. Then this would be a single retrieve operation (instead of 20 or more). Encapsulate the logic behind that so you can equally easy store this both inside the database and session, and easily manage and store them.

Apart from these general suggestions, I can not see much "load" with your question anyway. You need to do what you need to do. You could reduce the number of permissions if you want less hassle, but that will obviously not be useful as you want that.

And then, what's your problem with sessions? Or more specifically, what do you mean by load?

Comment: I don't mind storing them in a sessions, but i just read that it isn't a good idea to store too many variables in a sessions. Hence i was wondering for an alternative.

Comment: So you read that. And where you read that, which number was told to you is bad? And as you're at that point, into which concrete problem did you run? Was it bad for you? Have you verified that? You will find any opinion written somewhere in the internet, so better be careful.

Comment: It is a valid point that you should not store too much clutter in your sessions. I recently had to tune an application that had session files larger than 4MB - it was a nightmare. A relatively small set of permissions that are retrieved on every request are a perfect candidate for storage in the session.

Comment: Looks like what the OP read was not the point that the OP thought it was. Can't see anything close.